# Как в javascript извлечь часть строки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть входящие данные вида:
Текст №123
Текст №123/2
Текст #123
Текст #123/2

Как извлечь скриптом часть строки по маске 123 или 123/2 ?
Естественно, цифры могут быть любыми. После / могут быть как цифры, так и буквы
№ или # не должны выводиться. Только то, что после.
После № или # возможен так же пробел.

Comment: Возможно, с помощью регулярных выражений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если искомому значению обязательно должен предшествовать символ `№` или `#`, то я бы сделал в два этапа: поиск включая `№`/`#` и удаление из найденного лишних символов:

```js
const str = '8888Текст №123 Текст №123/2 Текст #555/ Текст # 123/2 7777';
console.log(str.match(/(№|#)\s?\d+(\/\d+)?/g).map(s => s.replace(/[^\d/]|\/$/g,'')));
```

Т.к. на текущий момент песочница SO не работает, [проверить можно на jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/dfw7mhtz/1/)